# Как модифицировать URL через chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, httpwebrequest

Я пишу расширение для браузера chromium и пытаюсь изменить **часть URL** в GET-запросе. Но я не понимаю, как вернуть измененный параметр? Важно, чтобы изменился только **параметр в URL**, а остальные хедеры остались.

Мне нужно изменить часть "**blabla**" на "**stopbla**". Например:

> До-----:    http://site.com/index.php?bla=blabla&end=false
>
> После: http://site.com/index.php?bla=stopbla&end=false

Замена проходит успешно. Но Fidler показывает, что посылаемые значения не изменились.

Я не могу использовать следующую конструкцию, так как она работает только в **onBeforeSendHeaders**. А так же потому что параметр *URL* находится за пределами параметра *requestHeaders*:

> return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};

[image: Посмотрите JSON-дерево запроса]

### Что я делаю не так?

background.js (часть)

```
    var callback = function (details) {
    if (details.url.indexOf('blabla') > -1) {

        bkg.console.log('++ Yes: ' + JSON.stringify(details.url));
        details.url = details.url.replace('blabla', 'stopbla');
    }

    return {url: details.url};

};
var filter = {urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], tabId: currentTabId};
var opt_extraInfoSpec = ['requestBody', "blocking"];

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec);
```

manifest.json (часть)

```
"permissions": [ "tabs","background", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://*/"],
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок, нашёл таки решение.

В параметре нужно указать только **'blocking'** и ничего больше! Это важно!

> var opt_extraInfoSpec = ['blocking'];

Метод слушателя использовать следующий:

> chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener

А в callback возвращать **redirectUrl** c *измененным* URL:

> return {redirectUrl: **modified_url**};